# How are these questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, meta

I asked https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103255/whats-the-best-way-to-learn-from-so and it was closed within a minute as a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34478/how-do-you-use-stackoverflow by [random](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) without a single comment.

I don't understand how they are the same. I was asking how people are managing posts from SO. If they are the same questions, shouldn't I be able to get an answer from the latter one? No, I can't find one. Could anyone explain how they are the same? Or is it also depending on reputation?

Comment: You have a comment now

Comment: Would you feel better if it was closed as "Not constructive"? Because it strikes me as yet another question that tries to use asking *about* learning as a substitute or stall tactic to avoid doing the actual learning. It's like asking "how do I learn this programming language?"--no one's going to give you an answer that learns the language for you. **You** have to put in the time and effort, and I don't see how these types of open-ended questions get anyone any closer to that goal.

Comment: @bemace, I don't feel anything about that. I am just trying to find a reason behind an action. If my question was not constructive, I am deserved to get that. But my question was marked as duplicate and I wanted to find out why. Do you understand that?

Comment: Ironically - you just learned something about the best way to learn from SO by having your question closed.

Comment: Aah, yet another shiny happy new user left beaten and bloody.  The internets are a dangerous place, kid.  You should always *lurk before you leap*.

Answer (score 9):

> Could anyone explain how they are the same?

People *use* Stack Overflow to get answers to questions (aka learn). So "How do you *use* Stack Overflow" is the equivalent to "How to you *learn from* Stack Overflow. I think we can assume that they weren't asking for *bad* ways to use it, so the "best" in your question doesn't differentiate it.

```
      How do you        |     use    | Stack Overflow | ?
           ≈            |      ≈     |        =       |
What's the best way to  | learn from | Stack Overflow | ?
```

---

> If they are the same questions, shouldn't I be able to get an answer
>   from the latter one? No, I can't find one.

If your question was a duplicate of a *bad* question, then no, you're not necessarily going to get an answer. But having two unanswered questions isn't any better than having one unanswered question, so closing it makes sense regardless.

> Or is it also depending on reputation?

Really? You think there's a conspiracy amongst the experienced users to pick on you? Or could it be that your question just wasn't that great and didn't fit with the [standards of the community](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)?

Comment: OK So according to your statements, closing a post should be based on how you put in the title without considering its content.

Comment: By the way, where did you learn english? I want to go there.

Comment: @TheFog: If you don't think the answers to the other question are useful or applicable to your question, the best thing to do is edit your question to *clarify the difference* between what you're asking and what is asked there. Getting into a grammatical debate isn't likely to accomplish anything. I'm rather offended by your last comment, considering I agree with bemace here, so I'm definitely not voting to re-open or likely to take much sympathy on you. Things work here the same way they do on SO: if you *don't* think it's a dupe, it's your job to make clear *in the question*.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether I agree with the dupe-closing, but your question could need a bit more focus. Is a bit on the broad side - it reminds me of asking "how do you cope with the complexity of the modern world?" - it's a perfectly valid question, but you could write a book trying to answer it.

Try making it more specific - what exactly are you looking to gain from StackOverflow? Do you have a specific field of interest? Are you looking to ask, answer, or just observe? What brought you here, do you have a specific technical issue? Do you want to answer questions and gain a reputation?

I can't guarantee anything, but a specific question about an *aspect* of using Stack Overflow (with a defined goal of what you want to do) would have at least a better chance of staying open.

Comment: You are right that question title is more general than it needs to be and my question have not well structured. I will try to improve that way. But I am not sure that's right reason for closing a question though. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Learning is such a nuanced and personal behavior that I don't think you'll be able to ask for guidance here.  Perhaps on programmers.

Hence, I believe most any version of your question will be closed because it solicits opinions more than facts.

As to your original question: Find something that works and **do it**.  Personally I tend to answer questions I know little about solely for the reason that I will need to do the most research and learn *the most* before answering.  That said -- personal *preference*.

As a final note: Had you asked about the particulars of say Peter M's (could someone add a link -- I'm in an airport on a blackberry :/  ) edit management program in .Net -- your question would be much more on topic (esp. here on Meta).

Lastly, I think @random's close as duplicate at least points you in the right direction whereas I (being much more inexperienced) would've suggested closing as off-topis or not a real question.